# Can I shorten a function name I use repeatedly?

Tags: c, formula

I have a long formula, like the following:

```
float a = sin(b)*cos(c)+sin(c+d)*sin(d)....
```

Is there a way to use `s` instead of `sin` in C, to shorten the formula, **without** affecting the running time?

Comment: `double (*s)(double) = sin;`

Comment: The only effect using `#define` to shorten `sin` to `s` is to make your code unreadable

Comment: It doesn't affect the runtime. It might slightly affect the time it takes to compile your program because it has to do the textual replacement every time. I wouldn't recommend it either way because if someone else looked at the resulting code, they won't know what it does. If you think that shortening `sin` to `s` will make your code more readable, then there are probably better ways to refactor your code.

Comment: If you use this often, make a function: `float calc(float a, float b, float c)`. Maybe you can use `va_arg` if there are a variable number of arguments. Also, optionally make it `inline`.

Comment: You could write an emac macro that writes for you `sin`, whenever you type e.g. `CTRL + s`. In Vim you could write once `sin` and then use the `.` to repeat typing that as many times as you want.

Comment: I understand there might be reasons to disagree with OP's coding style but this seems to be a perfectly valid and to-the-point question. I don't see why it should be downvoted.

Comment: Probably because a lot of folk here prefer code-readability to short-handedness. If the code if only for OP's eyes only, then fine, but if it's going to be read by others then they'll probably be prying their own eyes out! I have not downvoted it for the record.

Comment: Not downvoting but I encourage you to reconsider youe idea. Renaming standard library functions can create confusion for future code readers and maintainers. Make your expressions more readable by using whitespace and if necessary splitting them over more than one line.

Comment: BTW, if you want to fine-tune performance, there is always the option of inspecting the compiler output :) https://godbolt.org/z/mxrKlC

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree with you, I am a mathematics student. If a formula is very long, use `s` can make the code more readable. @rici reminded me, splitting formula over more than one line is also a good idea.  :)

Comment: Whatever reservations you might have on this idea, that does not make this a bad question. I don't understand the -5. In what way is this question not useful in the context of a Q & A site? Voting here ought not be along the lines of the policy adopted in the meta sites.

Comment: @Ben: A few summers ago I have a lovely break in California helping (for fun) on the wormhole modelling project for the film "Interstellar". Not only was the weather fantastic but we punched out a whole load of command-line C++ solving Einstein's field equations on some absolutely awesome hardware! Using natural units was impractical (a mere quixotic mathematician's invention). The speed of light is always `c` and crops up all over the place in relativity. Please, please, please don't abbreviate a trig function to it!

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you for your reminder, I have learned a lot from the friendly comments and answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are at least three options for using `s` for `sin`:

Use a preprocessor macro:

```
#define s(x) (sin(x))
#define c(x) (cos(x))
float a = s(b)*c(c)+s(c+d)*c(d)....
#undef c
#undef s
```

Note that the macros definitions are immediately removed with `#undef` to prevent them from affecting subsequent code. Also, you should be aware of the basics of preprocessor macro substitution, noting the fact that the first `c` in `c(c)` will be expanded but the second `c` will not since the function-like macro `c(x)` is expanded only where `c` is followed by `(`.

This solution will have no effect on run time.

Use an inline function:

```
static inline double s(double x) { return sin(x); }
static inline double c(double x) { return cos(x); }
```

With a good compiler, this will have no effect on run time, since the compiler should replace a call to `s` or `c` with a direct call to `sin` or `cos`, having the same result as the original code. Unfortunately, in this case, the `c` function will conflict with the `c` object you show in your sample code. You will need to change one of the names.

Use function pointers:

```
static double (* const s)(double) = sin;
static double (* const c)(double) = cos;
```

With a good compiler, this also will have no effect on run time, although I suspect a few more compilers might fail to optimize code using this solution than than previous solution. Again, you will have the name conflict with `c`. Note that using function pointers creates a direct call to the `sin` and `cos` functions, bypassing any macros that the C implementation might have defined for them. (C implementations are allowed to implement library function using macros as well as functions, and they might do so to support optimizations or certain features. With a good quality compiler, this is usually a minor concern; optimization of a direct call still should be good.)

Answer (score 16):

> if I use define, does it affect runtime?

`define` works by doing text-based substitution at compile time. If you `#define s(x) sin(x)` then the C pre-processor will rewrite all the `s(x)` into `sin(x)` before the compiler gets a chance to look at it.

BTW, this kind of low-level text-munging is exactly why define can be dangerous to use for more complex expressions. For example, one classic pitfall is that if you do something like `#define times(x, y) x*y` then `times(1+1,2)` rewrites to `1+1*2`, which evaluates to `3` instead of the expected `4`. For more complex expressions like it is often a good idea to use [inlineable functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) instead.

Comment: Macro substitution substitutes preprocessor tokens, not text.

Answer (score 9):

Don't do this.

Mathematicians have been abbreviating the trigonometric functions to *sin*, *cos*, *tan*, *sinh*, *cosh*, and *tanh* for many many years now. Even though mathematicians (like me) like to use their favourite and often idiosyncratic notation so puffing up any paper by a number of pages, these have emerged as pretty standard. Even LaTeX has commands like `\sin`, `\cos`, and `\tan`.

The Japanese immortalised the abbreviations when releasing scientific calculators in the 1970s (the shorthand can fit easily on a button), and the C standard library adopted them.

If you deviate from this then your code immediately becomes difficult to read. This can be particularly pernicious with mathematical code where you can't immediately see the effects of a bad implementation.

But if you *must*, then a simple

```
static double(*const s)(double) = sin;
```

will suffice.